# Highcharts not rendering with array loaded with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, arrays, highcharts

I just started using Highcharts but already got a problem.
I want to fill my graph with data from an Ajax call but it just shows a blank graph.

First i want to show you how I get my data:

```
<?php

require_once("mysql_config.php");
$query = "SELECT temp FROM daten ORDER BY daten.id DESC LIMIT 0,6";

$answer = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
$row;

while($row = $answer->fetch_array()){
    echo $row['temp'] . ",";
}

?>
```

The output of this looks like: **-20,0,0,7,0,0,100**

And my AJAX Function:

```
function ajax(website, element, callback) {
    var http = null;
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = website;

    if(http!=null){
        http.open("POST",url,true);
        http.onreadystatechange = function(){

            if(http.readyState == 4){

                var text = http.responseText;
                callback(text, element);

            }

        }//Ende readychange

        http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        http.send();

    }//Ende if(http2!=null)

}//Ende Funktion
```

the callback is my create_chart function

```
function create_chart(rawdata, element){

newdata = rawdata.split(",");

//var newdata = [-20,0,0,7,0,0,100];

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            type: 'line',
            renderTo: 'test'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Testchart'
        },
        subtitle:{
            text: 'Subtitle'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'This is it'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: "Test",
            data: newdata
        }]
});

 }
```

The problem is, that it only draws a graph without data while using ajax but when I use an "prefilled" array (like the the one I commented out) it works fine.

Comment: If you console.log(newdata) in your create_chart function what is the output?

Comment: Answer was solved but thank you for trying to help me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newdata` is a string and when you split it its pieces are strings.

"-20,0,0,7,0,0,100".split(",") = ["-20","0","0","7","0","0","100"]

Highcharts needs numbers, so after the split, `parseInt` them into numbers:

```
var rawdata = "-20,0,0,7,0,0,100";
var strdata = rawdata.split(",");
var newdata = []
for (var i = 0; i < strdata.length; i++)
{
   newdata.push(parseInt(strdata[i]));
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NYmu2/).

Answer (score 0):

Check the response coming through ajax having datatype as object or not. Because highcharts will work it the response is of datatype as object.

If it is returning as string then, convert it into object using 
eval('(' + response + ')')